# ui-router nested states with parameters throw extention

Tags: angular-ui-router

I'm trying to make some nested states with dynamic options.

This kind of states works fine: `app`, `app.process`, `app.process.step2`

But my situation is little different because I want to pass some data in URL.

Here is my states

```
  .state('app.process/:type', {
          url: "/process/:type",
          views: {
              'menuContent1': {
                  templateUrl: "templates/intro.html",
                  controller: 'IntroCtrl',

              }
          }
      })

      .state('step/:type/:step', {
          url: "/process/:type/:step",
          parent: 'app.process',
          views: {
              'proiew': {
                  templateUrl: "templates/processes/increase.html",

                  controller: "increaseCtrl",



              }
          }
      })
```

While trying to run this

```
 $state.go('step/:type/:step', {type:$stateParams.type, step:2});
```

I get an error

```
Error: Could not resolve 'new/:type/:step' from state 'app.process/:type'
    at Object.transitionTo (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:33979:39)
    at Object.go (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:33862:19)
    at Scope.$scope.goNext (http://localhost:8100/js/controllers/IntroCtrl.js:11:18)
    at http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:18471:21
    at http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:43026:9
    at Scope.$eval (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:20326:28)
    at Scope.$apply (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:20424:23)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:43025:13)
    at http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:10478:10
    at forEach (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:7950:18)
```

any suggestions?

Comment: pass parameters in different way

Comment: You need only :step and :type placeholders in url, not in state names

Answer (score 0):

there are many different ways to pass parameters to a state, first of all you can simply set the parameters on the click of the link and then take them from the scope.

but if we are talking on something more reliable and readable i suggest [this post](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki), and specifically i like using `Resolve`. i'll put here an example of resolve, but i encourage you to read and find out what works best for you:

```
$stateProvider
      .state("customers", {
        url : "/customers",
        templateUrl: 'customers.html',
        resolve: {

            // A string value resolves to a service
            customersResource: 'customersResource',

            // A function value resolves to the return
            // value of the function
            customers: function(customersResource){
                return customersResource.query();
            }
        },
        controller : 'customersCtrl'
      });
```

Comment: You can use 'data' parameter instead of resolve. But your approach do not allow you to get the specific customer by typing customers/123 in url